# How to set limit on Loading when playing video. I'm using Better Player Flutter plugin

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx, video-player, flutter-video-player

**When I play a video, it loads the entire video in the first 5 minutes itself. This consumes a lot of my data. I want  to load video as it as plays or just for the next five minutes. What functionality should I use for this so that my work becomes easy?**

```
  class VideoView extends GetView<VideoController> {
  VideoController videoController = Get.put(VideoController());
  late BetterPlayerController? _betterPlayerController;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Wakelock.enable();
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: AspectRatio(
          aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
          child: BetterPlayer.network(
            videoController.args[0],
            betterPlayerConfiguration: BetterPlayerConfiguration(
                aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
                controlsConfiguration:
                    BetterPlayerControlsConfiguration(enableFullscreen: false)),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void onClose() {
    videoController.dispose();
    Wakelock.disable();
  }
}
```

[Only 2 min video playback and 25 min loaded.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAK1b.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I got the answer  after reading lots of documentation. It was very important to me to reduce the user's data consumption. Most of the users/students were watching videos more than 6 hours in a day. If one hour video consumed more than 400MB-500MB It's not good at all. The user had limited ~1.5 GB Data per day.

The problem was only with the buffer which was running without limit.
`

```
    import 'package:better_player/better_player.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:get/get.dart';
    import 'package:wakelock/wakelock.dart';
    
    class VideoView extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _VideoView createState() => _VideoView();
    }
    
    class _VideoView extends State<VideoView> {
      late BetterPlayerController _betterPlayerController;
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        BetterPlayerConfiguration betterPlayerConfiguration =
            BetterPlayerConfiguration(
                aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
                autoDispose: true,
                autoDetectFullscreenAspectRatio: true,
                fullScreenByDefault: true,
                fullScreenAspectRatio: 16 / 9,//AR dual time but it's okay.
                controlsConfiguration: BetterPlayerControlsConfiguration(
                    enablePip: false,
                    enableFullscreen: true,
                    enableSubtitles: false,
                    loadingColor: Colors.deepOrange,
                    progressBarBufferedColor: Colors.red, //very useful
                    progressBarHandleColor: Colors.blue,
                    progressBarBackgroundColor: Colors.white));
        BetterPlayerDataSource dataSource = BetterPlayerDataSource(
          BetterPlayerDataSourceType.network,
          Get.arguments[2], <== deault quality url
          videoFormat: BetterPlayerVideoFormat.other, //don't forget it if not hsl
          resolutions: {
            "LOW": Get.arguments[3],      // url1
            "MEDIUM": Get.arguments[2],   // url2
            "HD": Get.arguments[1],       // url3
            "Full HD": Get.arguments[0],  // url4 
          },
     // Here is the problem and I resolve it in this way
          bufferingConfiguration: BetterPlayerBufferingConfiguration(
            minBufferMs: 5000,
            maxBufferMs: 131072,
            bufferForPlaybackMs: 2500,
            bufferForPlaybackAfterRebufferMs: 5000,
          ),
       // cacheConfiguration is very useful 
          cacheConfiguration: BetterPlayerCacheConfiguration(
              useCache: true,
              maxCacheSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024,
              maxCacheFileSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024,
              preCacheSize: 3 * 1024 * 1024),
        );
    
        _betterPlayerController = BetterPlayerController(betterPlayerConfiguration,
            betterPlayerDataSource: dataSource);
        super.initState();
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        Wakelock.enable();
        return SafeArea(
          child: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
            body: Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: AspectRatio(
                aspectRatio: 16 / 9, // AR for self satisfaction
                child: BetterPlayer(
                  controller: _betterPlayerController,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    
      void onClose() {
        _betterPlayerController.dispose(); // necessary
        Wakelock.disable();
      }
    }
`
```